# Eclipse C++: Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run

Tags: debugging, eclipse-cdt

I recently moved from Java to C++, and experiment using Eclipse CDT. I created a HelloWorld project, which compiled and run fine.

I then tried to enable the debugger, but couldn't get it running properly. Below is my debugger configuration (I am using gdb in Mac Sierra, gdb installed using homebrew, codesigned already). Please advice what additional setting I might need to do in order to get debugger work. Thank you!

[image]